# My branch is ahead of master...but I can't push to master

Tags: git, github

This may be a Git 101 type question, but....I've forked a repo and am pushing my commits to it, then submitting pull requests (all this is on GitHub) to the origin repo.  Periodically I'll pull from the origin to bring in the latest source from others.

That's been my workflow.  Currently though, when I run a `git status` I'm told that my master branch is X commits ahead of origin/master and that I should push to publish my changes.  I don't have those rights however.

I never push anything to my fork's master repo, I only do branches, push to them, then open a PR and eventually merge origin/master back to my master.  I'll then branch from master to start the cycle again.

I've pushed my changes to my fork, and have a PR outstanding, so would that explain the message?  Otherwise, since I can't push to origin will I have to just live with this message from here on out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that every time you checkout a new feature branch you do a `fetch origin` then `checkout origin/master` then base your branch off that: `git checkout -b my-new-feature`. If you didn't do this, you can do a `git rebase origin/master`